# typoscript TMENU ATagParams lowercase

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I was wondering if you can apply some text formatting to `ATagParams` in TMENU -
in case you need to have something like:

```
<a class="button category-button category-living" href="living/">Living</a>
```

Where "Living" is the Title of the page, as well as the specific classname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve some preprocessing for `ATagParams` values, one needs to create a cObject first:

```
ATagParams.stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
ATagParams.stdWrap.cObject { 
    case = lower 
    field = title
    insertData = 1
    wrap = class="button category-button category-|"
}
```

works like a charm.

Comment: originally found here: https://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/kategorie/menues/thema/85423/ (these links tend to deteriorate, so i thought of posting it here)